# Strange UTF-8 encoding issues when reading XML, writing results in C#

Tags: c#, xml, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm having an issue with a simple C# program that is meant to read an XML document from the web, pull out some elements, and then write the contents of those elements to an HTML file (in a simple table). Though the XML documents are correctly encoded as UTF-8, in the end, all of my generated HTML files are failing to correctly transcribe non-Western English characters (e.g. "Wingdings"-like output when parsing Japanese).

Since the XML files are really large, the program works by having an XmlReader yielding matching elements as it encounters them, which are then written to the HTML file using a StreamWriter.

Does anyone have a sense of where in a program like this the UTF-8 encoding might have to be explicitly forced?

Comment: Share the part of the code that creates the StreamWriter for saving HTML.

Comment: using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(outputFile,true,System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))

Comment: I found that using Text.Encoding.Default made other Western character sets with accents work (Spanish accents, German umlauts), although Japanese still exhibits problems. I assume this means that the problem is in how I am specifying the writing.

Comment: Does the font or editor you're using to look at the HTML support all unicode characters? Do your output HTML docs have the correct BOM?

Comment: Well, I'm not really specifying any particular font when writing the HTML tags, and am looking at the pages in Firefox, IE, and Chrome (all of which show the same issue). Is it possible that for some reason on an XP machine without Japanese characters installed, you simply cannot do this kind of transcription, even though such characters can be displayed properly in browsers and with other dev platforms (e.g. Python)? Not familiar with BOM.

Comment: Please post a minimal example. e.g., when reading from the web, are you reading byte arrays or a string?

Comment: Does the HTML output have a Content-Type speficying "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1".  If so, that could screw things up.

Comment: @picksels - the BOM is the Byte Order Mark that tells unicode-capable programs which particular encoding scheme to use to read the bytes. The UTF-8 BOM, for example, is 0xEF 0xBB 0xBF in the first three bytes of the file.  

The font is only important when displaying the data. If you don't have a capable font available that's capable of andling Unicode, multibyte characters may be interpreted as multiple one-byte charactes according to whatever code page is active.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The short explanation

I'm going to guess here: Your browser is displaying the page using the wrong character encoding.

You need to answer: What character encoding does your browser think the HTML is? (I bet it's not UTF-8.)

Try to adjust your browser: for example, in Firefox, this is View → Character Encoding, then select the character encoding to match your document.

Since you seem to have a very multilingual document, have your C# output in UTF-8 - which supports every character known to man, including Japanese, Chinese, Latin, etc. Then try to tell Firefox, IE, whatever, to use UTF-8. Your document should display.

If this is the problem, the you need to inform the browser of the encoding of your document. Do so by ([see this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML#Specifying_the_document.27s_character_encoding)):

- Having your web server return the character encoding in the HTTP headers.
- Specifying a character encoding in a `<meta>` tag.
- Specifying a character encoding in the XML preamble for XHTML.

The more of those you do, the merrier.

---

### The long explanation

Let's have a look at a few things you mentioned:

> using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(outputFile,true,System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))

and

> found that using Text.Encoding.Default made other Western character sets with accents work (Spanish accents, German umlauts), although Japanese still exhibits problems.

I'm going to go out on a limb, and say that you're an American computer user. Thus, for you, the "default" encoding on Windows is probably Windows-1252. The default encoding that a web browser will use, if it can't detect the encoding on an HTML document, is ISO-8859-1. ISO-8859-1 and Windows-1252 are *very* similar, and they both display ASCII plus some common Latin characters such as é, è, etc. More importantly, the accented characters are encoded the same, so, for those characters, the two encodings will both decode the same data. Thus, when you switched to "default", the browser was correctly decoding your Latin characters, albeit with the wrong encoding. Japanese doesn't exist in either ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252, and both of those will result in Japanese just appears as random characters. ("Mojibake")

The fact that you noted that switching to "default" fixes some of the accented latin characters tells me that your browser is using ISO-8859-1, which isn't what we want: We want to encode the text using UTF-8, and we need the browser to read it back as such. See the short explanation for the how to do that.

Comment: Thanks so much for the thorough explanation - this is exactly what the problem was. I figured enforcing UTF-8 was the trick, just didn't think to check the browser as well (duh).